# Formatting Java XMLGregorianCalendar in Spring REST response

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, spring-boot

I am calling a SOAP web based webservice and converting the response into REST and returning back to the consumer. The client is provided as a jar file. There is a field which is defined as XMLGregorianCalendar.

```
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType(name="date")
  protected javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar date;
```

When I print the value of date returned by the external service , I see the below :

> t.getDate() 2015-10-18
>    t.getStartTime() 2015-10-18T12:00:00
>    t.getEndTime() 2015-10-18T16:00:00

However I when I convert it to JSON using the below code -

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(resp)
```

I see the values getting converted to below -

> "date":1445227200000,
>   "endTime":1445295600000,
>   "startTime":1445284800000,

I saw that I can set the date format using the below -

```
        mper.setDateFormat(df);
```

However this sets the same format for all the fields. Is there a way to set different date formats for different dates in the same class? Also without using Jackson lib directly , is there a way to set this when use Spring REST framework to return the values?

Comment: Can you provide some code or something? I'm not sure I understand what you're doing.. That number is milliseconds since 1970-Jan-01, but I don't see any way of getting that directly out of an `XMLGregorianCalendar` without converting to some other object, so something strange is going on here.

Comment: It is currently return the millseconds. If I had access to the java file , I would have converted that to date and formatted it to return the value. Since I don't have access to the java file and it is a compiled class , is there a way to decorate it (possibly using refelction?) to convert this into a formatted date?

Comment: But how is it storing the millis in an `XMLGregorianCalendar`? That shouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry , I will check further.

Comment: Hi dcsolhl , I have provided additional updates

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?